# How to determine the line which a time-series fluctuating around

Tags: time-series, self-study, econometrics, white-noise

Let $X_t=1+3t+0.5X_{t-1}+ \epsilon_t$ be a trend-stationary model, where $\epsilon$ is a white noise, which has zero expected value and standard deviation.

Which line is the time series fluctuating around? And why?

Comment: Is this a homework question?  If so, please add the self-study tag and describe what you’ve tried so far.

Comment: I added the tag. I don't know how to start or approach the problem.

Comment: But you didn’t get this question out of the blue; you must have some existing knowledge about time series etc.  So where are you stuck specifically?   Make sure you understand what trend-stationary means.  Then determine what “fluctuate around” means specifically, in mathematical terms.

Comment: What would your answer be if all the $\epsilon_t$ were zero?  That might provide a good guess.  BTW, that's *exactly* the case with "zero ... standard deviation" as stated in your question, but I suspect you might have omitted a crucial word, such as "**constant** standard deviation."

Comment: I gave x(0) a value and calculated the first 20. From this, I got -4+6t. Does this might be a good approach?